# Should [memory] go down the memory hole?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burnination

This site has the tag [memory](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/memory), which is currently tagged on 17 questions and is very ambiguous. By my count, the questions are about the following:

- Amnesia/Memory loss, 4

  - Specific memory removal, 2
- Memory charm (Harry Potter), 3
- Reliving a memory, 3
- Memory transfer from one individual to another, 2
- Memory recording, 1
- Recalling a lost memory, 1
- Eidetic memory, 1

Some of these are about the general concept of remembering something (e.g. eidetic memory), others are about a recollection of an event and what you do with it, and others are about a spell.

One of the main points in [Jeff Atwood's guidelines for good tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/191265) is that a tag should have a clear, unambiguous definition and mean the same thing in all contexts. The fact that this tag has been used for eight different contexts indicates that it does not meet this criteria. Additionally, it can't stand on its own, so it's likely a meta tag.

Given this ambiguity, should [memory](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/memory) go down the [memory hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_hole) (i.e. burninate it)?

Comment: **Note:** if the consensus is to burninate this tag, it can be got rid of with a maximum of **seven questions edited** (edit it out of all the non-story-ID questions, then silently merge the tag into [tag:story-identification]).

Comment: I don't see any reason to keep memory.

Comment: Consensus seem clear, so will somebody please kill it? I'm not sure at which arbitrary point we're supposed to take action, but I know 2 things: 1) Successful tag changes have happened with less support 2) When I decide to do it before someone else gives the go ahead, people are not happy with me.

Comment: @CreationEdge Presumably someone with the ability to silently merge the tag, as Rand al'Thor suggested, should do it.

Comment: That's only necessary for the story id ones, mentioned. There's no reason the rest of the work needs be done by a moderator.

Comment: @CreationEdge Fair enough. I've removed it from all questions not also tagged with [story-identification]. There's 10 of them left (four were changed); not sure where Rand al'Thor got the number seven.

Comment: @Thunderforge Seven was the original number of questions tagged [tag:memory] but not [tag:story-identification]. I retagged three of them and you got the last four. And just now I did the final merge, so this is now [meta-tag:status-completed].

Answer (score 11, accepted):

,

[image: Kill it with fire]

Let it burn, let *it* burn
That stupid tag is gone
Here I stand
In the light of flaaaame
Let the tag burn ooooooooon

The tag never helped me anyway

Comment: Your reasoning is impeccable.

Comment: @Rand Pictures are worth 1000 words, especially when animated and we've already hashed out the words over and over. :D

Comment: One user flagged this as NaA, and presumably that's where the lone downvote comes from too.

Comment: This answer doesn’t have enough flamethrowers in it.

Comment: @amaranth Unfortunately true. Flamethrowers are like cow bells.

Comment: I'm flagging it as NaA as well, sorry. I happen to agree the tag is worthless and should be removed, but [animated GIFs are not a way to argue the point, on meta or otherwise](http://i2.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/000/490/542/8a0).